# Splitting string into two separate parts

Tags: javascript

Say I have a string that contains a domain:

```
var domain = "http://google.com";
```

Each time the script runs, I would like to break this script into two parts at random.

So if I were to run it the first time, it could give me these results:

```
part 1: http://go
part 2: ogle.com
```

The second run would produce:

```
part 1: http://goog
part 2: le.com
```

at complete random each time.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please be sure to take some time to review the [faq]. Questions here are typically expected to involve code in some way, and it's helpful for everyone if you show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). As it stands I can't see any effort on your part to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a random number between 0 and the string length. Grab a substring from that.

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var domain, number, pieces;

    domain = "http://google.com";
    number = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (domain.length - 1));
    pieces = [domain.substring(number, -number), domain.substring(number)];

    console.log(pieces);

}());​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KTPXt/

Answer (score 0):

Hey here's how I would do it.. maybe it would work for you as well.

```
        var domain = "http://google.com";

        var lengthOfdomain = domain.length;

        var post1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*lengthOfdomain)+1);

        var post2 = 0;

        if(post1==lengthOfdomain){
           if((lengthOfdomain%2)==0){
              post1 = lengthOfdomain/2;
              post2 = post1;
            }else{
               post1 = (lengthOfdomain-1)/2;
               post2 = post1+1;
            }
        }else{
            post2 = lengthOfdomain-post1;
        }


        if(post1>post2){
           var dom1 = domain.substr(0,post2);
           var dom2 = domain.substr(post2,post1);
        }else{
           var dom1 = domain.substr(0,post1);
           var dom2 = domain.substr(post1,post2);
        }

        alert(dom1+' + '+dom2);
```